# How to divide the maximum value of two separate df columns in pandas within a multi-layer groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following df:

```
Account      Code      Revenue     Expenses
Account 1    123       6           10
Account 1    123       2           10
Account 1    345       1            6
Account 1    345       3            6
Account 1    345       2            6
Account 2    678       2           12
Account 2    678       1           12
Account 2    678       3           12
Account 2    890       1           2
```

How do I get a set of repeating values for the max Revenue (grouped by Code and by Account) divided by max Expenses. So this would be the desired output:

```
Account      Code      Revenue     Expenses   Ratio
Account 1    123       6           10         .6
Account 1    123       2           10         .6
Account 1    345       1            6         .5
Account 1    345       3            6         .5
Account 1    345       2            6         .5
Account 2    678       2           12         .25
Account 2    678       1           12         .25
Account 2    678       3           12         .25
Account 2    890       1           2          .5
```

I was thinking something like the following but this doesn't appear to work:

```
max_df['Ratio'] = max_df.groupby(['Account']['Code'], sort=False)['Revenue'].max() / max_df.groupby(['Account']['Code'], sort=False)['Expenses'].max()
```

I get an error that states

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `mean`:

```
max_df['Ratio'] = (max_df.groupby(['Account','Code'])['Revenue'].transform('max') / 
                   max_df.groupby(['Account', 'Code'])['Expenses'].transform('max'))
print (max_df)
     Account  Code  Revenue  Expenses  Ratio
0  Account 1   123        6        10   0.60
1  Account 1   123        2        10   0.60
2  Account 1   345        1         6   0.50
3  Account 1   345        3         6   0.50
4  Account 1   345        2         6   0.50
5  Account 2   678        2        12   0.25
6  Account 2   678        1        12   0.25
7  Account 2   678        3        12   0.25
8  Account 2   890        1         2   0.50
```

You can avoid double `groupby` by list of columns for processing after `groupby`, then is possible use [`DataFrame.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) for divide

```
max_df['Ratio'] = (max_df.groupby(['Account','Code'])[['Revenue','Expenses']]
                         .transform('max')
                         .eval('Revenue / Expenses'))
```

... or create helper `DataFrame`:

```
df = max_df.groupby(['Account','Code'])[['Revenue','Expenses']].transform('max')
max_df['Ratio'] = df['Revenue'] / df['Expenses']
```